# else if clause is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want an open-close function. If the `<div>` is open  it should close when I click it, and when I click it again it should re-open. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lmj7wcbm/)

HTML

```
<div class='answer'>answer</div>
  <div style='display:none'>
    <textarea name='talking'></textare>
    <input type='submit'>
</div>
```

Jquery

```
$('.answer').click(function(){
    if($(this).next().css('display','none')){
        $(this).next().css('display','block');
    }else if($(this).next().css('display','block')){
        $(this).next().css('display','none');
    }
})
```

In this example the "if" clause is working (it opens), but the "else if" does not work (it does not close again).

Answer (score 2):

Within your conditional statements, you should be *retrieving* the element's `display` property and comparing it with a string of the properties' value.

So that rather

```
if ( $(this).next().css('display', 'none') ) {
    // ...
}
```

It should be:

```
if ( $(this).next().css('display') === 'none' ) {
    // ...
}
```

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lsqk3g0y/)

```
$('.answer').click(function () {
    if ($(this).next().css('display') === 'none') {
        $(this).next().css('display', 'block');
    } else if ($(this).next().css('display') === 'block') {
        $(this).next().css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

---

Your code could be simplified to the following, though:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/b7hazk9z/)

```
$('.answer').on('click', function () {
    $(this).next().toggle();
});
```

The [`.toggle()` method](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) handles all this logic.